# How do I run a command after a ssh connection, without disconnecting?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ls, ssh-config

I want to run a command automatically after I connect to another machine via ssh, without the ssh session being closed automatically.

After searching the internet I found some solutions but none of them work the way I need.

```
ssh bla@bla "ls"
```

This runs the `ls` command on the remote machine, shows me the output and closes the connection.

I also tried editing the ssh config file with

```
Host bla
        HostName bla
        User bla
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
        RemoteCommand ls
        RequestTTY force
```

Same issue, this connects via ssh, runs the `ls` command, shows me the output and then exits. Not even the `RequestTTY` option helped.

```
ssh bla@bla "ls ; bash"
```

This doesn't disconnect after running `ls`, but I don't get a full terminal interface, just some bare bones command line that doesn't show the `me@machine:~$ thing`.

What I actually want:

Either some bash alias, or `.ssh/config` entry that will allow me to type in a simple command which will connect to the remote machine and then run a command there and leave the terminal open.
Basically as if I did this by hand:

type

```
ssh blah@blah
```

and then after it connects I would type

```
ls
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> ssh bla@bla "ls ; bash"
> ```
>
> This doesn't disconnect after running `ls`, but I don't get a full terminal interface, just some bare bones command line that doesn't show the `me@machine:~$` thing.

If you specify a command (e.g. `ls ; bash` above) the SSH server will not provide a pseudo-terminal. You have observed exactly this.

On the other hand sole `ssh bla@bla` allocates a pseudo-terminal by default. So this is what you want. Force pseudo-terminal allocation, use `-t` or `RequestTTY`.

> Not even the `RequestTTY` option helped.

It won't help you if the remote command is `ls` only. You need `ls; bash` or similar.

It seems when you requested a tty, you did not request `bash`. And when you requested `bash` after `ls`, you did not request a tty. You need both:

```
ssh -t bla@bla "ls; bash"
```

Note `ls` will also use the pseudo-terminal. Please read the "broader picture" section of [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1557724/432690) to learn the difference (especially where it reads "there's a quirk").

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of me@machine you need to set the PS1 environment variable. Try:

```
ssh bla@bla "PS1=\"\"; ls; bash"
```

Comment: I was docked on this. But it does meet the requirements of the question. It allows the user to type in a simple command (ssh bla@bla "PS1=\"\"; ls; bash" ) which connects to the remote machine and then runs a command there (ls) and leaves the terminal open (bash). It is a bare bones command that doesn't show the  me@machine:~$ thing.